# Filter shopify xml file to show products by collection

Tags: xml, parameters, filter, shopify

Shopify have a sitemap xml file that you can see all your products with:

```
http://myshopifysite.com/sitemap_products_1.xml
```

They have a parameter you can append to the url to filter these products by date

```
http://myshopifysite.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=386970543&to=467983291
```

My question is, has anyone used a parameter to filter this url by collection? So for example something like:

```
http://myshopifysite.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?collection=xxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file contains only the list of your Shopify products (all). The fields are: product url, product name, date of creation, product image url, how often should the web bots recheck the product. As you can see there's absolutely no reference to the collection/s any product belongs to, so NO, you can't filter by collection.
This file is intended for bots (it's an improvement of the classic sitemap.xml) so I wouldn't rely on anything on this xml file. You can create a specific xml file to show tons of data, there you'll probably be able to do lots of magic. Here you have an example: http://www.telepienso.com/pages/criteo-feed4445

Comment: Sure, but what might help other users in the future is a json file I just found. http://myshopifystore.com/admin/products.json?collection_id=29399967

Comment: @AlexDavin right alex, but the json is private. Unless you have a session open you won't be able to see it. See that in your question you showed an open to anyone file. That's the reason of giving you the public page built using a specific page template which we can share if you need it